# Shifting to a disjoint subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subset \mathbb{A}^8$ be a subvariety of dimension 3.
Show that there is a vector $v\in k^8$ such that $(X+v)\cap X=\emptyset$.
(remark: $X+v=\{x+v|x\in X\}$)

Comment: This seems too easy to be a solution, but I can't see where it goes wrong: if the statement is not true, then there is an $x \in X$ such that for all $v \in k^8$, we have $k+v \in X$. But then $X$ contains a subspace of greater dimension than itself, which is a contradiction. (can you see the mistake, @GeorgesElencwajg?)

Comment: Did you mean: "there is an $x\in X$ such that for all $v\in k^8$, we have $x+v\in X$"? But it's not necessarily the same $x$ for all $v$...

Comment: Dear @Frederik, pumpam is right. The negation of the proposed statement is that for every $v\in k^8$ there exist $x,x'\in x$ with $x+v=x'$. But both $x$ and $x'$ would depend on $v$.

Comment: Perhaps we should try first with lower numbers. For example, let $X\subset \mathbb{A}^2$ subvariety of dimension 0. So X is just a finite collection of points. Since each point of $X$ can be in only finitely many subsets of the form $(X+v)\cap X$ we can use cardinality consideration to claim there must be some empty such sets. Can anyone suggest a more 'algebraic' proof? Can we extend it to higher numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the difference morphism $d:X\times X\to k^8: (x,x')\mapsto x-x'$.
Its image $Y=d(X\times X)\subset k^8$ is not necessarily closed (but is constructible: Chevalley's theorem).
We may  however consider the closure $\overline Y\subset k^8$ of that image: that closure is an affine variety.
The morphism between affine varieties $d:X\times X\to \overline Y$ is dominant (meaning has dense image), so that $\text {dim}(\overline Y)\leq \text {dim} (X\times X)=6$.
This implies that $\bar Y\subsetneq k^8$ and *a fortiori* that $Y\subsetneq k^8$.
Hence there exists a $v\in k^8\setminus Y$.
That this vector $v$ is not in the image $Y$ of $d$  means exactly that for all $x,x'\in X$ we have  $v\neq x-x'$ or equivalently that $(X+v)\cap X=\emptyset$ , just as required.

Comment: You say 'morphism between affine varieties', but $X$ is just a variety.

Comment: The usual interpretation of subvariety of $k^8$ (without any supplementary qualification) is closed subvariety and thus automatically affine variety. If you think that a locally closed variety is meant, take its closure and apply my result.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking locally closed. So taking the closure wouldn't change the dimension?

Comment: No need to answer, I figured it out. Cool proof, BTW.

Comment: I'm happy we now agree @pumpam. And thanks for the kind words.